# How to handle error in a Resolver

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to use resolvers in order to make a better UX. Everything works great on the happy path. What I can't seem to figure out is how to handle exceptions. My resolver calls a service, which hits a webapi project. An example:

**FooResolver:**

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Foo> {
      return this.fooService.getById(route.params['id']).catch(err => {
    ****not sure what to do/return in the case of a server error****
    return Observable.throw(err);
  });
}
```

**FooService:**

```
  public getById(id: string): Observable<Foo> {
    return this.http.get(`${ this.apiUrl }/${ id }`)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**The handleError function:**

```
   protected handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // Todo: Log the error   
    // Errors will be handled uniquely by the component that triggered them
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Inside the FooComponent, I do this (this is never hit in the event of an error returned from the service/resolver):

**FooComponent**:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.foo= this.route.snapshot.data['foo'];
    if (this.foo) {
       this.createForm(this.foo);
    }
}
```

I've tried throwing the error (as shown) - I get this exception in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error
>   for URL:

and returning `new Observable<Foo>()`, which gives:

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

I have a few resolvers, all of which can experience exceptions on the server, But I don't know what to do in the event of these exceptions.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here is an example of one of my resolvers with error handling, using the technique that Gunter suggests:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { IProduct } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Injectable()
export class ProductResolver implements Resolve<IProduct> {

    constructor(private productService: ProductService,
                private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProduct> {
        let id = route.params['id'];
        if (isNaN(+id)) {
            console.log(`Product id was not a number: ${id}`);
            this.router.navigate(['/products']);
            return Observable.of(null);
        }
        return this.productService.getProduct(+id)
            .map(product => {
                if (product) {
                    return product;
                }
                console.log(`Product was not found: ${id}`);
                this.router.navigate(['/products']);
                return null;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(`Retrieval error: ${error}`);
                this.router.navigate(['/products']);
                return Observable.of(null);
            });
    }
}
```

You can find the complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing in the APM-final folder.

**UPDATE Feb 2019**

Here is a better answer for error handling in a resolver:

1. Wrap your interface in another interface with an optional error property:

```js
/* Defines the product entity */
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  category: string;
  tags?: string[];
  releaseDate: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  starRating: number;
  imageUrl: string;
}

export interface ProductResolved {
  product: Product;
  error?: any;
}
```

2. Resolve to that interface:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ProductResolved } from './product';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductResolver implements Resolve<ProductResolved> {
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<ProductResolved> {
    const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
    if (isNaN(+id)) {
      const message = `Product id was not a number: ${id}`;
      console.error(message);
      return of({ product: null, error: message });
    }

    return this.productService.getProduct(+id).pipe(
      map((product) => ({ product: product })),
      catchError((error) => {
        const message = `Retrieval error: ${error}`;
        console.error(message);
        return of({ product: null, error: message });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

3. In the component, pull off the piece of the interface you need:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  const resolvedData: ProductResolved = this.route.snapshot.data['resolvedData'];
  this.errorMessage = resolvedData.error;
  this.product = resolvedData.product;
}
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, as it gives me a more complete example. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Always resolving to something, even when an error occurs, kind of contradicts with the purpose of resolve. By using resolve, I'm saying that the component responsible for this route, needs this information, and if for some reason, the information is not available, it should not be rendered. Promise (Observable) rejection inside resolve guard do this and prevents rendering route's component, but there should be a uniform mechanism to catch resolve errors and handle them with some component for error handling.

Comment: better to do `Observable.throw(theError);` instead of null

Comment: Watching your lecture from NGConf on YouTube, googling issues and first answer I see - it's you again lol

Comment: @AlirezaMirian what would you recommend instead? I'm also not sure about navigating to the component when I have an error because one of the purposes of a resolver is to prevent showing a partial page. That's easy when your're navigating from a previous page. You just stay there, but what about if you press f5 on a page that uses a resolver? What should I do in that case?

Comment: Yes, I think navigating to an error route or even keeping user in the previous route are both bad UX. That's why I think it should be a routing-level feature, to be able to specify error component for your routes, maybe with inheritance support for nested routes, so that you can provide a default error handler component (which is able to show general http errors like Not found, Access denied, etc.) on a top level and override it in special cases down the routing hierarchy. I'm not following Angular closely in last couple of years, so not sure if such feature is added to angular router or not.

Comment: It depends much on the specific scenario. If it is that the user lacks access to the requested page, it makes sense to keep the user in the previous route. If the user makes some selections and the selections can't be found, it also might be nice to stay on the selection page so the user can modify their options. So, it depends. :-)

Answer (score 16):

You need to return an observable that completes with `false`

```
handleError() {
  return Observable.of([false]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I accepted the other answer as it gives a more complete example.

Answer (score 12):

I only wanted to provide a very similar updated answer but with some updated code. I personally think the error should simply not be managed inside the resolver.

Why? Well, **I think that the resolver's job is to resolve, not to figure out what to do if it can't resolve**. We might be using this resolver in two or three different components, and each of them might decide to react in a different way if the resolver fails. We might want to redirect in one of them to a 404 page, but in other maybe we just try to fix graciously the error by displaying something else.

Sure, we might also want to react differently depending on what error we get: maybe the user was not authorised, or maybe that item was deleted or didn't even exist on the first place, who knows. We might want to display different results and in that case I totally upvote *DeborahK*'s updated answer. But for most cases, I think that overcomplicates the matter (an extra interface only for the resolver, making sure the error inside it's descriptive...) and that we probably won't really care why the resolver failed: it just did, let the component that needed that item figure out what to do, and move on.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import { Product } from '../_interfaces';
import { ProductsService } from '../_services';

@Injectable()
export class ProductResolver implements Resolve<Product> {

    constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) {
    }

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        const id = route.paramMap.get('id');
        return this.productsService.getProduct(id).pipe(
            catchError(error => {
                console.error(`Can't resolve product with id ${id} because of the error:`);
                console.error(error);
                return of(null);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I myself discovered this quirk by chance. 

I must also note that as a result of error catching this way inside the resolver, now somehow you can catch the error inside your component class. Go figure!

Answer (score 1):

At times you do not want the component the user trying to navigate to to be in charge of the resolver error. You would rather leave it with the current component.

In these cases, returning such values as `null` or `false` from the resolver is not the solution (it still causes the navigation to end successfully). The solution is to throw an error inside the resolver:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderResolver implements Resolve<Order> {
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Order> | Promise<Order> {
    return throwError(() => new Error("Can't load")); //use Promise.reject(new Error("Can't load")) if you're working with promises
  }
}
```

So, the current component, which is waiting for the navigation result, could address this error in such a way:

```
async navigateToOrder(id: string): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const result: boolean = await this.router.navigate(['orders'], { 
      queryParams: { id: id }
    });
    console.log(`all is ${result}`); //would be false if guards have not allowed to proceed, true otherwise
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error("something's gone wrong"); //notify your user of the loading error here
  }
}
```